# Convert method to string in c#?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a method to a string, or there is any way to convert a method to a string in order to print the method result as a string in c#?

Comment: It is completely unclear what are you asking for. If you want to print result of method, why you want convert a method to string? You mean convert body print of method? Or what?

Comment: I mean print the result of method yes, but it his not necessary to convert it to a string to sent it to the screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get method name you can use [reflection](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-method-names/). If you want the result of the method to be string you can just convert the value of it to string in a way convenient to you or the business logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking. From the comments it seems you want to print to a screen. You should know that all objects have a `ToString()` method which is called on any type of print. You can `override` this in your class to provide a proper result in the event your instance is printed.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string SomethingCool => "Hey!";
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return this.SomethingCool;
    }
}
```

You can:

1. Return a `string` from your method to begin with;
2. Return the type you have now and explicitly call the `object`'s `ToString()` in your printing method (saves time at runtime as the type doesn't have to be boxed);
3. If simply calling `ToString()` on your instance doesn't work, override the `ToString()` method and put whatever result you care to see.

Comment: Anyone know why indenting the code when below a list doesn't format properly? Is that something for Meta?

Comment: Nah, I would close it as a duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255372/code-block-bug-when-following-numbered-list

Comment: @rene cool thanks for the link. I didn't think I'd be the first to encounter it, but also wasn't sure if that's a type of question for a meta format.